# Minimum Order Amount ignored

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart

Can anyone imagine why the minimum order amount is going to get ignored (or not checked) although every settings are controlled a couple of times and store configs as well (the are all taking the settings of the main configuration).

I did an output of the storeconfig amount in the cart and the right value is there as well.

Comment: Did you check the setting in store view label?

Comment: I debugged the value directly with getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount') and it stated the correct amount.

Comment: I wonder where it is ignored. On the catalog page? In the checkout? What does the error/behaviour look like?

Comment: It's ignored on the cart and at the checkout so I can place an order no matter how high the minimum amount is. No errors are going to displayed as I didn't activate the minimum order amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the company which installed and configured everything added a return true; directly after function start validateMinimumAmount in Model - Quote - Address